# Next js graphql-yoga server 404 on api route

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql

I am new to using graphql-yoga 3 with next js to create apis using grapghql. Unfortunately my routes `/api/graphql` return 404 despite the fact that i have followed the example [here](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/yoga-server/docs/integrations/integration-with-nextjs). The default page loads well but i can seem to figure out why the routes are not found.
I have this mesage on `/api`

```
If you expected this page to be the GraphQL route, you need to configure Yoga. Currently, the GraphQL route is configured to be on /api/graphql.
```

Any advise/links to read will be appreciated.

Code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/boring-mountain-kntfjk?file=%2Fpages%2Fapi%2Findex.tsx%3A15%2C1)

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer [here](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-yoga/issues/2696)

You have to do this :

```
export {
 yoga as GET,
 yoga as POST
};
```